# apt-get upgrade won't update gimp from the ppa

Tags: apt, ppa

I've been playing with the Ubuntu Mini 18.04 LTS ISO tonight and tried to install a ppa for GIMP because 2.8 just won't cut it. The ppa I used is `ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp`.

Doing apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, it shows that nothing was upgraded. I installed update-manager to see if it can do it, but it claims that my system is up to date.

Looking at the output of the terminal for apt-get upgrade and apt-get install gimp, one thing caught my eye, `and 1 not upgraded`. I'm not sure exactly what that means and how it can help me, I just have a feeling that's important to this. Here's some terminal output to start with.

```
james@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Fetched 177 kB in 1s (288 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
james@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gimp-data
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
james@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gimp is already the newest version (2.8.22-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Output of `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade`.

```
james@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Output of `apt-cache policy gimp gimp-data`.

```
james@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy gimp gimp-data
gimp:
  Installed: 2.8.22-1
  Candidate: 2.8.22-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.22-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gimp-data:
  Installed: 2.8.22-1
  Candidate: 2.10.8+om-0ubu18.04.3~ppa
  Version table:
     2.10.8+om-0ubu18.04.3~ppa 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.8.22-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade`.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy gimp gimp-data` to the question.

Comment: I've added the info in the original post.(idk if just editing will notify commenters, please correct me on that)

Answer (score 0):

You also can install it from Flatpak.
https://www.gimp.org/downloads/